# Any suggestions for fixing the multiple vertices that are unnecessary and cause issues with face orientation?

Tags: vertices

I'm having a lot of issues with unnecessary lines and vertices for my file.  I'm not sure why some are clear (top left) and some are incredibly wild (middle and top left)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the decimate modifier set to planar? Some of your issues might also go away if you just merge by distance in edit mode.